# How to execute more than one shell scripts in a task in gradle file

Tags: java, shell, gradle, scripting, build.gradle

I'm new to gradle, I have a scenario where I need to execute 2 shell scripts in a single task in gradle.

I tried the below, but it is not executing the script1.sh task.

```
task downloadtheArtifacts(type: Exec) {
    commandLine './script1.sh'
    commandLine './script2.sh'
}
```

Please let me know how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that :

```
task downloadtheArtifacts {
    doLast {
        exec {
            commandLine './script1.sh'
        }
        exec {
            commandLine './script2.sh'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above piece of code without doLast aswell, it worked. Do we need to put doLast or doFirst in this case?

Comment: You should use `doLast`, because otherwise the scripts will be executed everytime you invoke Gradle on this project, not only if this specific task is executed. It would be the same as without the task definition (just the `exec` closures, try it out!).